# How to decode unicode-encoded JSON in PHP with Zend\Json\Json::decode(...)?

Tags: php, json, unicode, zend-framework2

I'm writing a client for an API...

```
use Zend\Http\Client;
use Zend\Http\Request;
use Zend\Json\Json;
...
$request = new Request();
$request->getHeaders()->addHeaders([
    'Accept-Charset' => 'UTF-8',
    'Accept' => 'application/hal+json',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/hal+json; charset=UTF-8',
]);
$apiAddress = 'http://my.project.tld/categories';
$request->setUri($apiAddress);
$request->setMethod('GET');
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->dispatch($request);
$data = $response->getContent();
```

... and get a unicode encoded JSON like this:

```
...{"id":"7","title":"\u0438\u043b\u043b\u044e\u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u0446\u0438\u0438","short_name":"\u0418\u041b\u041b\u042e\u0421\u0422\u0420\u0410\u0426\u0418\u0418"...
```

First I tried to decode it with [`json_decode(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). But I didn't find any appropriate method to do this in PHP (without suspect regex based approaches).

Now I'm trying it with [`Zend\Json\Json::decode(...)`](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.json.objects.html#json-objects) and getting following error:

```
/var/www/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zend-json/src/Json.php:243
Decoding failed: Syntax error
```

**How to get a unicode-encoded JSON decoded with `Zend\Json`?**

---

**EDIT**

Just notices, that the JSON is broken. It is separated to two parts. The string starts with `1f9e`, then the first part, then the string `\u043`, then the second content part, then `0`.

```
1f9e <-- What is it?
{"_li...
\u043 <-- What is it?
1a6...
tfoli <-- What is it?
0
```

Comment: Are you sure the JSON is valid?

Comment: I've also tested it with Postman. So, yes, I think, I can be sure, that it's valid. But encoded.

Comment: Wait, maybe you are right. Just put the API call's output from Postman's "pretty" view to the `Json::decode(...)` -- works. Then I put the same output from the "raw" view. I expected it not to work. But actually it have worked as well. So, it really seems to be a problem with the JSON I get from `Zend\Http\Response#getContent()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Zend\Json\Decoder` component of ZF2. It has a static method called `Decoder::decodeUnicodeString()` which decodes unicode characters.

Please have a look at the script [here](https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework/blob/release-2.4.11/library/Zend/Json/Decoder.php#L88).

Hope this would help you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! +1 But Actually the problem is in my case in the broken JSON. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44978260/2019043) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I see this json doesn't seem to be broken. Please consider the next code lines:

```
$data = '{"id":"7","title":"\u0438\u043b\u043b\u044e\u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u0446\u0438\u0438","short_name":"\u0418\u041b\u041b\u042e\u0421\u0422\u0420\u0410\u0426\u0418\u0418"}';

$json = json_decode($data);

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo $json->title;
echo "<br/>";
echo $json->short_name;
```

the result is:

```
иллюстрации
ИЛЛЮСТРАЦИИ
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but please see the **EDIT** in my question and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44978260/2019043), because -- you are right -- the JSON by itself is OK, but it comes with some additional symbols at the beginning and at the end. The JSON between these additional strings is actually valid. But all together gives an invalid JSON string.