# How get a valid JSON output from the response in Zend Framework 3?

Tags: php, json, zend-framework3, zend-http-client

I'm writing a client for an API...

```
use Zend\Http\Client;
use Zend\Http\Request;
use Zend\Json\Json;
...
$request = new Request();
$request->getHeaders()->addHeaders([
    'Accept-Charset' => 'UTF-8',
    'Accept' => 'application/hal+json',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/hal+json; charset=UTF-8',
]);
$apiAddress = 'http://my.project.tld/categories';
$request->setUri($apiAddress);
$request->setMethod('GET');
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->dispatch($request);
$data = $response->getContent();
```

... and get a broken JSON like this:

```
1f9e <-- What is it?
{"_links...
\u043 <-- What is it?
1a6...
tfoli <-- What is it?
0
```

The string is separaten into five lines:

- 1st line: only `1f9e`
- 2nd line: first content part
- 3d line: string `1a6`
- 4th line: the second content part
- 5th line: `0`

**Why am I getting additional symbols/strings? How to avoid this a get valid JSON output?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the `getContent()` method of the response object. It may not decode the content it gets in it from the request. Please have a look at [here](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-http/blob/master/src/Response.php#L336). This might be the reason. I may be wrong!

So the `getBody()` method of it does the decoding job for the content of the request. So please use this method instead of `getContent()`.

```
$data = $response->getBody();
```

Hope this would help you!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I didn't use the `getBody()` because I trusted in the autocomplete function of my IDE. The `Zend\Http\Client#dispatch(...)` returns a `Zend\Stdlib\ResponseInterface`. I didn't consider it and, when I so only `getContent(...)` and `getMetadata(...)`, I thought, that the `getBody(...)` were not provided anymore. But sure, the concrete object returned by the `dispatch(...)` is a `Zend\Http\Response` and it provides the method I need -- `getBody()`. Now it's working. Thanks a lot!